# Trying to display stats in table form, keep getting "Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):" errors

Tags: javascript

So, I made this app to receive feedback from customers and process them into a table form. It works as I assume, but issue is the console sends back "Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):" errors such as:

```
"Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>."

"Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>."

"Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>."

"Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>."
```

My code looks as follows:

```
const Statistic = (good, neutral, allClicks) => {

  return (
    <tbody>
      <tr text="Goodvotes" value ={good} />
      <tr text="Neutralvotes" value ={neutral} />
      <tr text="Badvotes" value ={bad} />
      <tr text="Allvotes" value ={allClicks} />
    </tbody>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  const [allClicks, setAll] = useState(0)

  if (allClicks === 0) {
    return <div>
    <Display />
    <Button handleClick={() => {
      setGood(good + 1) 
      setValue(value + 1) 
      setAll(allClicks + 1)}} text="Good" />
    <Button handleClick={() => {
      setNeutral(neutral + 1) 
      setValue(value + 0) 
      setAll(allClicks + 1)}} text="Neutral" />
    <Button handleClick={() => {
      setBad(bad + 1)
      setValue(value - 1) 
      setAll(allClicks + 1)}} text="Bad" />

    <div><h1>Statistics:</h1></div>

    <div>Statistics are shown by placing a vote.</div>

  </div>
  }




  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <Display />
      <Button handleClick={() => {
        setGood(good + 1) 
        setValue(value + 1) 
        setAll(allClicks + 1)}} text="Good" />
      <Button handleClick={() => {
        setNeutral(neutral + 1) 
        setValue(value + 0) 
        setAll(allClicks + 1)}} text="Neutral" />
      <Button handleClick={() => {
        setBad(bad + 1)
        setValue(value - 1) 
        setAll(allClicks + 1)}} text="Bad" />



      <h1>Statistics:</h1>



      <Statistic good={good} />
      <tr>Good feedback:<td>{good}</td></tr>
      <Statistic neutral={neutral} />
      <tr>Neutral feedback:<td>{neutral}</td></tr>
      <Statistic bad={bad} />
      <tr>Bad feedback:<td>{bad}</td></tr>
      <Statistic all={bad + good + neutral} />
      <tr>All feedback:<td>{bad + good + neutral}</td></tr>
      <Statistic average={value} />
      <tr>Average:<td>{value}</td></tr>
      <Statistic percentpositivetotal={good / allClicks * 100} />
      <tr>Percentage positive:<td>{good / allClicks * 100} %
</td></tr>

 </tbody> </table>

  )


 }

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I know it is something to do with my usage of < div > but I am not able to actually pinpoint the area of issue. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is standard table structure, that had been violated here, you can see some kind of result in the output and browser shows you the warnings, you can read more about the table element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table); but let me tell in summary why is that happening;

table should made up of `row`s and `column`s. so you need to define the rows and columns, by using `<tr>` element as the first-level child of `<tbody>`, you'd made the rows; now for the columns you should use `<td>` element as the fisrt-level child of the `<tr>`. and inside the `<td>` you can render your stuff ( there are some limitations though );
in summary every things you have should inside `<td>` or `<th>` for the headers.

here is valid table structure with some react elements inside it as an example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">some header</th>
            <th colspan="2">another header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><SomeReactElement /></td>
          <td><AnotherReactElement /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I re-arranged my stats and also react elements respectively and now everything works. Big thanks for helping me with this.